# Nontriviality of cup products

Tags: algebraic-topology, duality-theorems

Let $M$ be a close, connected, orientable manifold.

If $0 \neq \alpha \in H^q (M^n; \Lambda) $ for $q \neq 0,n$ then, is there a $\beta \in H^{n-q}(M^n;\Lambda)$ with $\alpha \cup \beta \neq 0$?

This question arises from Bredon's Topology and Geometry on page 359 Prop 10.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily.  For instance, let $M=\mathbb{R}P^3$ and $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $H^2(M;\Lambda)=\mathbb{Z}/2$ but $H^1(M;\Lambda)=0$, so no such $\beta$ exists for the nontrivial $\alpha\in H^2(M;\Lambda)$.

More generally, for $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}$, if $\alpha$ is a torsion element of $H^q(M;\Lambda)$, then no such $\beta$ can exist, since $\alpha\cup\beta$ would be a torsion element of $H^n(M;\Lambda)=\mathbb{Z}$ and the only such element is $0$.

Comment: How about the case $\Lambda = Q$? Is there a possibility that my question is true?

Comment: Yes, then it is true by Poincaré duality.  Exactly how you deduce it depends on what statement of Poincaré duality you have.